# Grails 3 use springSecurityService in a trait? Serialization error-

Tags: spring-security, ehcache, traits, grails-3.0

To add a username "lastUpdatedBy" property (along with some other std properties) to several domain classes I created a trait.  Everything works fine to the database, but EhCache disk storage gives a NotSerializableException on springSecurityService.  I have

```
def springSecurityService
```

in order to get the principal.username.

Is there a way to designate the service as transient (static transients=[] doesn't seem to help), or am I at a dead end? Referencing a service from within a domain class is a bit dodgy anyway, but what is a better, workable way to get the username just before saving?

Comment: you should've simply define `transient springSecurityService` in your domain class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.  One of the domain classes had a composite key and was therefore tagged to implement Serializable.  Once this was converted to maintain the usual id field and "implements Serializable" was removed, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your the field as a transient field.

```
class MyDomain {

    // other stuff omitted

    transient SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

}
```

This will do the job when it come to serialization.